# Como evitar de página ser exibida em outra aba

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho esse jquery

```
$(window.document.location).attr('href', '/gerenciarpdv');
```

E esse botão chama essa página

```
<button id="teste1" name="teste" class="btn-pesquisa" onclick="ChamaGerencia();">GerenciarPDV</button>
```

O problema é que a página está sendo exibida em outra aba. Como evitar isso?

Comment: Que evitar, ou forçar a página ser aberta noutra janela?

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você pode estar fazendo do seguinte modo:

```
window.open("/gerenciarpdv","_self")
```

Ou

```
location.href = "/gerenciarpdv"
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eLPT/)

<sub>*Não sou conhecedor do jQuery, por isso acredito que possa haver soluções mais apropriadas.*</sub>

Comment: Ok, mas em outro formulário eu faço do mesmo jeito que o postado e funciona, ou seja, não abre em outra aba.